# 'telegram.error.TimedOut: Timed out' problemnn

Tags: python

I ran into a problem with my telegram-bot program. when I launch it, after few minutes this error shows up. is it related to my internet connection ? or the code is wrong ?

the code:

```
import time
import datetime
#pip3 install python-telegram-bot --upgrade
import telegram
import asyncio
#pip install asyncio
import nest_asyncio
#pip install nest-asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

bot = telegram.Bot(token='MY-BOT-TOKEN')

chat_id = 5559185333

while True:
    nt = str(datetime.datetime.now().time()) + "pycharm"
    print(datetime.datetime.now().time(), "pycharm")
    asyncio.run(bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=nt))
    print(datetime.datetime.now().time(), "pycharm")
    time.sleep(10)
```

the error:

```
    raise TimedOut from err
telegram.error.TimedOut: Timed out
```

I checked the network problem, but it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: You left your **Private Bot Token** in your code. You should revoke it **ASAP** by talking to the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). People might abuse the token.